# Create multi levels at the same row

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have an intermediate output like this

```
Parent    Child
P1        C1
P1        C2
C1        D1
C2        E1
D1        F1
E1        G1
F1        H1
```

I'm trying to build an output with all the levels in a single row in SQL Server

Sample Output:

```
Columns:  L0    L1      L2        L3      L4
Values:   P1    C1      D1        F1      H1
          P1    C2      E1        G1
```

Any inputs?

I tried with recursive query using CTE to achieve the intermediate output. Need help to achieve the final output as shown in the sample output

Answer (score 1):

Here is one approach if you have a fixed or maximum number of levels.  The first part is a standard recursive CTE where we build a JSON string .  While the final portion just parses the JSON string

**Example**

```
Declare @YourTable Table ([Parent] varchar(50),[Child] varchar(50))  Insert Into @YourTable Values 
 ('P1','C1')
,('P1','C2')
,('C1','D1')
,('C2','E1')
,('D1','F1')
,('E1','G1')
,('F1','H1')
 

 ;with cteP as (
      Select Child
            ,Parent 
            ,COC  = cast(Parent+'","'+Child as varchar(max))
      From   @YourTable 
      Where  Parent = 'P1'
      Union  All
      Select r.Child
            ,r.Parent 
            ,COC  = p.COC+'","'+cast(r.Child as varchar(max))
      From   @YourTable r
      Join   cteP p on r.Parent  = p.Child)
Select L0 = jSON_VALUE(JS,'$[0]')
      ,L1 = jSON_VALUE(JS,'$[1]')
      ,L2 = jSON_VALUE(JS,'$[2]')
      ,L3 = jSON_VALUE(JS,'$[3]')
      ,L4 = jSON_VALUE(JS,'$[4]')
      ,L5 = jSON_VALUE(JS,'$[5]')
 From cteP A
 Cross Apply ( values ('["'+COC+'"]')) B(JS)
 Where Child not in (Select Distinct Parent from @YourTable)
```

**Results**

```
L0  L1  L2  L3  L4      L5
P1  C2  E1  G1  NULL    NULL
P1  C1  D1  F1  H1      NULL
```

Comment: The maximum level is not a fixed value and it will be dynamic based on the overall dataset

Comment: @Osceria SQL Server is declarative by design.   Your requirement would require Dynamic SQL.

Comment: @Osceria Just curious... Why does your desired results include a Level 5 when there would not be one in your sample data?

Comment: It shouldn't be there. Corrected the question

Comment: While I applaud the effort, I think the OP wants "fully dynamic hierachical pivoting". No can do, without Dynamic SQL.

Comment: @TheImpaler Thanks.  The dynamic requirement bubbled up after the fact.  Saw the original L5 and assumed he had a max depth hierarchy.   I often question the need for dynamic columns... because they would need to be consumed dynamically.   Feels like a slippery slope.